# IActiveScriptParse32::ParseScriptText Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, scriptengine, jint

Has anybody ever faced a memory leak problem with IActiveScriptParse32::ParseScriptText when using it in C#?
I need a ScriptEngine that is able to parse JavaScript-Code. (Everything works fine, except the used memory)

The problem is, that the longer my passed JavaScript-Code is, the more unmanaged memory is allocated by the function "ParseScriptText".

I have no idea how to free the allocated space. I actually already run Marshal.ReleaseComObject(parse32) after parsing my script but somehow the used memory does not go down anymore.

Comment: There are very good chances that the problem, if any (you're using managed code so are you sure there's a true memory leak) lies in your code. Can you provide a reproducing project so we can take a look at it? Also, since you're using C#, the way you do interop also matters a lot.

Comment: You can use [ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/) or examine how they have done by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/search?q=ParseScriptText%28&unscoped_q=ParseScriptText%28). `Windows` namespace in the project is the place.

Comment: Hi guys, first of all thank you for your answers.
I actually found an alternative solution. I tried JINT. (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) It works perfectly and does not have a memory leak or something. The only problem: It is casesensitive... This is a big problem for my project. Is there any way to ignore uppercase/lowercase in my scripts?

Comment: You should delete your question now

Comment: "Questions with open bounties cannot be deleted" ;)